# Making text bolder with strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, stroke, bold

In Illustrator, I am trying to make my text bolder by adding a stroke to it. The stroke is the same color as the text, but when saving as SVG, the stroke is considered separate from it, adding unnecessary code. Is it possible somehow to make a letter with a stroke only one object? Thank you very much.

Comment: what program do you work with?

Comment: What you need to do is to create outlines of your text, but as @Ilan says, we need to know what software you are using to tell you _how_ to do it.

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry, I use Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the text
- Choose `Type > Create Outlines` from the menu (*Note:* text will no longer be editable live type after this. Work on a *copy* if you need to have text editable for later use.)
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu (if available)
- Choose `Object > Expand` from the menu (if available)
- Click the `Merge` or `Unite` buttons on the **Pathfinder Panel** (Not the effect menu)

Answer (score 6):

I would do a slightly different thing from Scott.. I would *not* put an outline on the text, and go:

`type` -> `create outlines`

then

`object` -> `path` -> `offset path`

That gives you a few options, and you can choose how much thicker you want the text:

[image]

This should give you an xml-file that is manageable: 
[image]